# How can I make Disqus comments not show up on pages?

Tags: pages, comments, disqus

I use Disqus to manage my comments. I'd like it to appear only on posts, and not on pages. How can I do that?

If there's a way to selectively show it on some pages that'd be great, but in general I'd like the default to be hidden on pages.

Comment: I have written and explained a small plugin to disable comments on pages: [How to disable comments for WordPress pages in any theme](http://wpengineer.com/2302/how-to-disable-comments-for-wordpress-pages-in-any-theme/). It replaces the regular `comments_template` for pages with a file that returns nothing – and therefore no disqus comments too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Dashboard > Pages . Click on 'Edit' for the page you want to hide comments on.
2. On the top of this screen you'll get `Screen Options`, Expand this section.
3. Check/Enable the `Discussion` button.
4. Scroll down on the screen. Uncheck the `Allow Comments` option.

Answer (score 0):

Nitin's solution works, however, **if you have comments already on the page Disqus will not disappear.**

Therefore you need to go into the Wordpress Page you want Disqus removed from:
Goto Dashboard > Pages > Edit Page

Then go to the comments in Edit Page view and "Trash" them all. Then Disqus will not show up.

Hope this helps. I Googled for an hour looking for the solution until I figured it out on my own!